# Transparency issue while using PIL's paste method

Tags: python, image, rotation, python-imaging-library

Since PIL doesn't seem to be able to create an ellipse at an angle, I wrote a function to do this. The problem is, when I paste using PIL, it doesn't seem to use the alpha information. Does anyone know why is the transparency information being dropped if all the images are RGBA?

Thanks in advance!:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

def ellipse_with_angle(im,x,y,major,minor,angle,color):
    # take an existing image and plot an ellipse centered at (x,y) with a 
    # defined angle of rotation and major and minor axes.
    # center the image so that (x,y) is at the center of the ellipse
    x -= int(major/2) 
    y -= int(major/2) 

    # create a new image in which to draw the ellipse
    im_ellipse = Image.new('RGBA', (major,major), (255,255,255,0))
    draw_ellipse = ImageDraw.Draw(im_ellipse, "RGBA")
    
    # draw the ellipse
    ellipse_box = (0,int(major/2-minor/2),major,int(major/2-minor/2)+minor)
    draw_ellipse.ellipse(ellipse_box, fill=color)

    # rotate the new image
    rotated = im_ellipse.rotate(angle)
    rx,ry = rotated.size
    
    # paste it into the existing image and return the result
    im.paste(rotated, (x,y,x+rx,y+ry))    
    return im
```

If I then try calling it like so:

```
im = Image.new('RGBA', (500,500), (40,40,40,255))
im = ellipse_with_angle(im,x=250,y=250,major=300,minor=200,angle=60,color=(255,0,0,255))
im = ellipse_with_angle(im,x=300,y=200,major=100,minor=75,angle=130,color=(255,0,255,150))
im = make_color_transparent(im,(0,0,0,255))
im.show()
```

I get this:

[image: output image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding a `mask` when pasting as follows:

```
im.paste(rotated, (x,y,x+rx,y+ry), mask=rotated)
```

e.g.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

def ellipse_with_angle(im,x,y,major,minor,angle,color):
    # take an existing image and plot an ellipse centered at (x,y) with a 
    # defined angle of rotation and major and minor axes.
    # center the image so that (x,y) is at the center of the ellipse
    x -= int(major/2) 
    y -= int(major/2) 

    # create a new image in which to draw the ellipse
    im_ellipse = Image.new('RGBA', (major,major), (255,255,255,0))
    draw_ellipse = ImageDraw.Draw(im_ellipse, "RGBA")

    # draw the ellipse
    ellipse_box = (0,int(major/2-minor/2),major,int(major/2-minor/2)+minor)
    draw_ellipse.ellipse(ellipse_box, fill=color)

    # rotate the new image
    rotated = im_ellipse.rotate(angle)
    rx,ry = rotated.size

    # paste it into the existing image and return the result
    im.paste(rotated, (x,y,x+rx,y+ry), mask=rotated)    
    return im


im = Image.new('RGBA', (500,500), (40,40,40,255))
im = ellipse_with_angle(im,x=250,y=250,major=300,minor=200,angle=60,color=(255,0,0,255))
im = ellipse_with_angle(im,x=300,y=200,major=100,minor=75,angle=130,color=(255,0,255,150))
#im = make_color_transparent(im,(0,0,0,255))
im.show()
```

Which should give you something like:

[image: ellipses]